# How to properly display subsections in a timeline

Tags: ios, timeline

Lets say in a table view for the selected chapter, there is a list of the sections. Section one is labeled as "Article 1". "Test 1..3" are subsections of section 1. What is an appropriate way of graphically displaying this? A margin for the subsection titles is appropriate but was about the timeline? If all the icons are vertically aligned, it gives a feeling that all rows are section.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the size of the text and the tick colour of the subsections, for example:

[image]